# Flash player debug problem

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flashplayer-debug

I have installed flash player 10,1,82,76. When i tried to debug my application, it returned this alert message ..

C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\NPSWF32.dll

Flex Builder cannot locate the required debugger version of Flash Player. You might need to install the debugger version of Flash Player 9 or reinstall Flex Builder.

Do you want to try to debug with the current version?

And When i tried to install flashplayer_10_ax_debug.exe, i got this message.

"The version of Adobe Flash Player that you are trying to install is not the most current 
version. Please visit the Player Download Center to obtain the latest, most secure version."

What is the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

What browser are you targeting? You may need to disable/remove the current version before continuing with the debug player install. I went through this process before for testing diff player versions (9, 10) in IE, Firefox and Chrome, and detailed it [here](http://bishoponvsto.wordpress.com/2010/12/09/installing-flash-player-9-firefox-chrome-for-testing/)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when I was trying to debug my application with an internal Eclipse web browser. When I changed preferences so that debug started in external web browser like Firefox or Opera, problem disappeared.

Hope that it'll be of any help to you.